# How to make not to blink when item in ListView is touched

Tags: android, android-listview

In the case of normal ListView, if user touch one of items in ListView.
touched item blink one time. I want that it doesn't blink.

### How to configure ListView like above?

I've figured out myself. If we set color or textColor attribute, this problem resovled.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom listview and set the color change of the listview item on click same as that of the background. So that it will appear there is no blink !!

Hope it helps !!

Comment: I already tried to set background color of item, but it didn't bring me any changes. but, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Set this in your list view xml:

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: can you post the xml layout code you have for your list. and any java code in case you set any other attributes to the list via java.

Comment: I've figured out it myself. The reason of blinking is not relative with ListView. TextView in item of ListView, has this attribute 'android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"'. this attribute changes textview. if we set xml selector to textColor, its color doesn't changed when item in ListView is touched.

Comment: why not use android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" instead?

Comment: @ademar111190 Haven't tested it, does it work as well? Feel free to edit / add it as an alternative my answer.

Comment: I tested and works normal, @android:color/transparent is equals a #00000000 so it's only to a better pattern :). I'll edit.

Comment: @ademar111190 of course.. you're right. I somehow always had #00FFFFFF vs. transparent in mind, but #00000000 of course is transparent. will edit the answer. thanks for the hint.

Answer (score -1):

In **ListView** xml just add this two lines inside ListView

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" 
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```